# SQL Server : looking up multiple indexes for 1 row (and finding those indexes)

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, lookup

Right now I have a column called labels in my table `data`. It includes comma separated labels and is of type `varchar(254)`.

I have another table `lookup` with the indexes these labels to their correct codes.

I have another column in the `data` table called `code` that I want to populate with 1 code based on any of the comma-separated labels.

How do I go about

1. Separating the labels dynamically
2. Checking to see if any of the labels are found in the `lookup` table and if so, updating my "code" field to reflect what was found

Thanks for any help, sorry it is a complicated question.

I started by using substrings and looking up individual labels but I can only do 1 at a time and ran into trouble getting the middle or end values.

Comment: *It includes comma seperated labels and is of type varchar(254).* This is where your core problem is. Normalize your data and avoid this problem and many others!

Answer (score 2):

One method is `outer apply` using `like`:

```
select d.*, l.code
from data d outer apply
     (select top (1) l.*
      from lookup l
      where ',' + d.labels + ',' like '%,' + l.label + ',%'
    ) l;
```

Note: You may need a cast if `l.label` is not a string.

Then, you can start working on fixing your data model, by creating a junction table with one row per label.  Storing multiple values in a single column is not the right way to store things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip/ I tried this but it still seems to only get the first value. I will try to make more columns for labels.